# Cocoa rotated element disappears after window resize

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a window with two pop up menus along the x and y axis of a custom view as seen in Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfKi5.png).

When I rotate the Y-axis popup view with the following code:

```
[YPopUp setFrameCenterRotation: -90.0];
```

I get the desired result shown in Figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4bt1.png).

However, after a window resize, the popup disappears as seen in Figure [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdn1T.png).  What can I do to fix this?  My guess is constraints?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**
As a desperate attempt to fix it I added the following lines of code but still disappears after resize

```
- (void)windowDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    YPopUp.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, plot.frame.origin.y + plot.frame.size.height, plot.frame.size.height, YPopUp.frame.size.height);
}
```

[image: Figure 1. Xcode view of pop up buttons]
[image: Figure 2. Runtime view before resizing]
[image: Figure 3. Runtime view after resizing]

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout or springs and struts?

Comment: Auto Layout.  But I removed constraints for the popup that is supposed to be vertical, otherwise it doesn't show up at all during runtime.

Comment: Well, without it, it won't layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution but I added constraints to the vertical NSPopUpButton to be 20px from the left and up against the top window.  When resizing it doesn't disappear and works, however sometimes I see it move slightly down during resizing.